# How to code the program to return to the code before if-else statement

Tags: java, if-statement

If at the end of my program i want to ask the user if he wants to perform an operation again using a if-else statement

```
System.out.println("What Is The Length Of Side A In cm?");
sideA=read.nextDouble();

}

System.out.println("What Is The Length Of Side B In cm?");
sideB=read.nextDouble();

}

System.out.println("The Triangle Hypotenuse ="+Hypotenuse(sideA,sideB)+"cm");

System.out.println("Do you want to preform this operation again, answer  with yes or no "); 
answer=input.next();
if (answer.equals("no") || answer.equals("No"))
  repeat=false; 
} else
  continue; 
}
```

Now if i try to compile the code i get an error in the "continue" statement
i am not sure how to make the program perform the operation again.

Comment: `continue` is for loops, not for `if-else`s

Comment: You forgot the while loop?!

Comment: Please post, at the very least, your entire method.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean repeat = true;
while (repeat) {
    System.out.println("What Is The Length Of Side A In cm?");
    sideA = read.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("What Is The Length Of Side B In cm?");
    sideB = read.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("The Triangle Hypotenuse = " + Math.hypot(sideA, sideB) + " cm");
    System.out.println("Do you want to preform this operation again, answer with yes or no"); 
    answer=input.next();
    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
       repeat = false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using a `while` loop for this

```
int choice = 1;
  while(choice != -1)
  {
      //code
      System.out.println("again?");
      //get choice
      if(user said no)
       choice = -1;
   }
```